# How can I invoke a AWS lambda function running on SAM localhost:3001 using java code

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I could not find any method in AWSLambdaClientBuilder class where in you can pass a url to invoke a lambda.

If there is a different way please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using version 1 of the Amazon SDK, it would be something like:

```
AWSLambda awsLambda = AmazonLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
     .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:3001/","us-east-1"))
                     .build()
```

Comment: I used the above code and got the following exception:
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:

Comment: Is your SAM environment running?

Comment: Yes it is running on port 3001 localhost

Comment: Thanks stdunbar for the support in addition to your answer, the SAM local env on which lamda will be running should have AWS credentials and region you use to invoke